# How to detect request type in Node Express JSON/HTML

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, express

I simply want to know if the request coming in is a standard page load or if the request has come from an `ajax` request.

Basically, I would like to use the same controller for both my ajax and my normal loading of a page.

Currently I am using:

```
      console.info(req.get('Content-Type')); //undefined.
```

Here is the node code I am using

```
getFixtures: function (req, res) {
  var passData = {}
  console.info(req.get('Content-Type'));
  passData.params = req.params;
  leagues(app).getLeagues(passData)
    .then(filterBarFixtures)
    .then(function () {
      res.render('games', {
        title: 'Fixtures and Results',
        passData: passData
      })
    });
  }

app.get('/fixtures/', controllers.getFixtures);
```

**2 way of loading the same controller**

Open a browser and navigate to `/fixtures`

or

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/fixtures"
})
```

Comment: as Content-Type is a **response** header, there's no point looking for it in the request headers

Comment: ah... so if I just look for it in the response  headers :)

Comment: Ok, so its still undefined with the response.

Comment: **no**, seeing as your server code would set the response headers ... you need to determine through the use of headers you set in the client specifically for your purpose, or perhaps query paramaters

Comment: Ah thank you for your help. Then this would be the answer I am looking for. I will google for this and it should be pretty simple. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers again

Comment: `$.ajax` usually sets `X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest` request header

Comment: If the request is for JSON, jQuery usually sets `Accept:application/json, text/javascript, ...`

Comment: Yes, thankfully jquery has done this for me with `      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("ajax",true);
      }`

Comment: that works too!

Comment: Amazing mate lol thank you, again if you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to either set a header in the client request to look for in the server, or perhaps a search/query parameter

However, as you are using jQuery you don't need to worry

jQuery `$.ajax` uses `XMLHttpRequest`, which sets `X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest` request header

Additionally, if the request is for JSON (using `$.ajax` with appropriate settings or `$.getJSON`), jQuery usually sets `Accept:application/json, text/javascript, etc`

note, I've said "usually" to cover my butt in case in some strange browser this doesn't happen :p

Your comment regarding

> beforeSend: function(request) { request.setRequestHeader("ajax",true); }

Is probably the safest option, as that header is guaranteed to be present, so that's the header to look for on the server side.